# Help proving $\lvert x-y\rvert - 3\lvert y\rvert \leq \lvert x + 2y\rvert$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, proof-verification

Prove $|x-y| - 3|y| ≤ |x + 2y|$

I figure I will have to prove by four cases, and for each prove the left hand side and then the right hand side. for case1: $x≥y, y≥0.$ case2: $x≥y, y<0.$ case3: $x<y, y≥0.$ case4: $x<y, y<0.$

But I'm not even sure where to start to prove the left hand side. For case 1 $|x-y|$ is the same as $x-y,$ and since y is greater than or equal to zero, then $|y| = y,$ but then how do we prove $|x-y| - 3|y|$?

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks everyone. So the triangle inequality made it a lot simpler to solve, but if I were to be asked to solve the problem using proof by cases on an exam, is it possible to add $$3|y|$$ to both sides and still preserve the inequality to prove that? So instead of proving  $$|x-y| - 3|y| ≤ |x+2y|$$ , can I instead prove  $$|x-y| ≤ |x+2y| + 3|y|$$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: think at the triangle inequality for $|(x+2y)-3y| \le \cdots$

Answer (score 0):

By Triangle Inequality ($|a+b| \leq |a|+|b|$)

$$|x-y|-3|y| \leq |x|+|y|-3|y|=|x|-2|y|$$
By reverse triangle inequality

$$|x|-2|y| \leq |x+2y|$$

Answer (score 0):

Because
$$|x+2y|+3|y|=|x+2y|+|-3y|\geq|x+2y-3y|=|x-y|$$
We can use also the following reasoning.
$$|x+2y|+3|y|=\sqrt{(x+2y)^2+9y^2+6|(x+2y)y|}=$$
$$=\sqrt{(x-y)^2+6xy+12y^2+6|(x+2y)y|}\geq$$
$$\geq\sqrt{(x-y)^2+6xy+12y^2-6(x+2y)y}=$$
$$=\sqrt{(x-y)^2}=|x-y|$$