# prove by case |x-y| - 3|y| ≤ |x+2y| - possible solution?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, proof-verification

So there is an easier way to solve this problem by using the proven triangle inequality theorem, but if I were to solve this with proof by cases, can I add $$3|y|$$ to both sides of the equation and prove for that or would this be considered a different proof? So instead of proving:

$$|x-y| - 3|y| ≤ |x+2y|$$ I instead prove for $$|x-y| ≤ |x+2y| + 3|y|$$
Then for case1: $$x≥y,y≥0$$, then $$x-y≥0.$$
Leftside = $$|x-y| = x-y$$ by definition as $$x-y≥0$$
Rightside = $$|x+2y| + 3|y| = x+2y+3y$$ since $$x≥y,y≥0$$
Therefore $$|x-y| ≤ |x+2y| + 3|y|$$

Is this a valid to do?

Comment: Sure, you can prove such a statement by cases, but you must consider all possible cases.  So, you've also got to deal with ($y<0$ and $x\geq y$), as well as ($y\geq 0$ and $x<y$), and ($y<0$ and $x<y$).

Comment: @Jamie It's good pratice to link previous posts on the same topic ([Help proving $\lvert x-y\rvert - 3\lvert y\rvert \leq \lvert x + 2y\rvert$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2187414/help-proving-lvert-x-y-rvert-3-lvert-y-rvert-leq-lvert-x-2y-rvert)) even though the questions are not technically duplicates.

Comment: Thanks, I'll remember that next time. Yeah, I realize there's 3 other cases I need to account for but I used case 1 as an example for what I've done so far.

Comment: @MichaelBurr so it's okay for be to add 3|y| to both sides and then prove that equation?

Comment: Sure, the first statement is true if and only if the second one is true.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Thanks! that makes it a lot easier :)